# How can I load code and then run it only when a key is pressed

Tags: python, pyautogui, pysimplegui

I'm working on a Python script using PyAutoGUI and PySimpleGUI. I've already made the window with a couple buttons, but I can't figure out how to "load" a block of code when I click a specified button, and then run it only when a key is pressed. Any ideas? I only managed to make the script work when I click the button.

Thanks!

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyautogui
import time

def func(moveMouse):
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150, duration=2)

layout = [[sg.Button('1'), sg.Exit()] ]

window = sg.Window('Script Test').Layout(layout)

while True:            
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == '1':
        func('Test 1')
window.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "load" the code?

The only thing I can think of with this info is assigning the function to a variable when you click the button and linking a keypress to running the variable.
This way the content of the intermediate variable can be changed.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was trying to mean, like I would click the button, and then with a determined key I can activate the script, but I would also code different scripts for each button, so you would have to first click the desired button, and then run the assigned script to the button when the key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

With option `return_keyboard_events=True` in `sg.Window` to generate event when any key pressed and released.

```py
import pyautogui
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(step):
    pyautogui.moveTo(100*step, 100*step, duration=0.2)

layout = [[sg.Text('Press key "123456789" to move mouse pointer, or "Q" to quit')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, return_keyboard_events=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Q', 'q'):
        break
    print(repr(event))
    if event in '123456789':
        step = int(event)
        func(step)

window.close()
```

Comment: This is kind what I wanted to do, but I was thinking on having to first press a button on the gui, and then with the key run the script, since I would code different scripts to every button.

Btw, thanks for improving the code! I'll keep the corrections in my mind.